# Cannot Change top CSS for Slider Revolution Navigation Arrows

Tags: html, css, slider

We're using a Slider Revolution template (https://revolution.themepunch.com/overexposure-transition-effect/) on our site, but for some reason the slide navigation arrows are showing a `top: 50% !important;` value. This is making the arrows appear halfway down the slide, rather than at the bottom as it should be.

We can't seem to find where this top value has come from.

You can see our slider here: http://holdsfoundation.org

Any advice appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Please describe what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You add Top 100% important to #rev_slider_11_1 .uranus.tparrows this class.

```
#rev_slider_11_1 .uranus.tparrows {
top: 100% !important;
background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an CSS file names 1523871058index.css. In this CSS at line 26

```
.rev_slider_wrapper .rev_slider .tp-leftarrow.tparrows, .rev_slider_wrapper .rev_slider .tp-rightarrow.tparrows {
    opacity: 0.8 !important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50% !important;
    margin-top: -31px !important;
    width: 63px !important;
    height: 63px !important;
    background: none;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
}
```

This style has `top: 50% !important;`.
just change it as either `top: 100% !important;` or remove it, Both works fine